# Overload template operator= for two templates: template<...> A = template<...> B and vice versa

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I am implementing two template classes where either class shall have an assignment Operator for the other class:

```
// prototype of template B
template<uint32_t nQ> class B;

// template A
template<uint32_t nQ> class A
{
    public:
        A<nQ>& operator = ( const B<nQ>& b );
};

// template B
template<uint32_t nQ> class B
{
    public:
        B<nQ>& operator = ( const A<nQ>& a ) { ... }
};

// Operator = for class A
template<uint32_t nQ>
A<nQ>& A<nQ>::operator = ( const B<nQ> b ) { ... }
```

so far, so good. Works perfectly. But now I want to have assignment Operators for different values of nQ. While it is no Problem to do that in template B I am not able to get it to work for template A:

```
// prototype of template B
template<uint32_t nQ> class B;

// template A
template<uint32_t nQ> class A
{
    public:
        A<nQ>& operator = ( const B<nQ>& b );
};

// template B
template<uint32_t nQ> class B
{
    public:
        B<nQ>& operator = ( const A<nQ>& a ) { ... }

        /*
         * I want to have this operator in template A as well
         */
        template<uint32_t otherQ>
        B<nQ>& operator = ( const A<otherQ>& ) { ... }
};

// Operator = for class A
template<uint32_t nQ>
A<nQ>& A<nQ>::operator = ( const B<nQ>& b ) { ... }
```

Unfortunately operator= cannot be implemented as a friend function. I have tried almost everything, but I don't get it done.
As an important Information: I am using a C++14 Compiler on a self-made embedded Hardware (STM32 + IAR Embedded Workbench).
I would really appreciate help here.

Thanks, Tim

Comment: Sorry about that, this is the auto correction for the german language. It always does that.

Comment: I had to manually correct everything and I missed that one.

Comment: The Problem is solved, though. Thanks.

Comment: In future questions, please choose one c++ standard, it doesn't make sense to tag as both `c++11` and `c++14`. If you're using a later compilation mode, tag as that

Answer (score 2):

Following should works:

```
// prototype of template B
template<uint32_t nQ> class B;

// template A
template<uint32_t nQ> class A
{
public:
    template <uint32_t OthernQ>
    A<nQ>& operator = ( const B<OthernQ>& b );
};

// template B
template<uint32_t nQ> class B
{
public:
    B<nQ>& operator = ( const A<nQ>& a ) { ... }

    template<uint32_t otherQ>
    B<nQ>& operator = ( const A<otherQ>& ) { ... }

};

// Operator = for class A
template <uint32_t nQ>
template <uint32_t OthernQ>
A<nQ>& A<nQ>::operator = ( const B<OthernQ>& b ) { ... }
```

Syntax for method template inside class template requires 2 `template`.

Comment: Oh man, Yes it indeed works. Sometimes I have a feeling I do not see the wood because of all the trees... All the things that I have been trying, I did not see this great and simple solution.